# Django - value from database not appearing in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, python-3.x

I have a calendar which is suppose to be connected to the current admins-association. When admin picks a date in the calendar and need to fill the form. Association-dropdown-list won't show any data from database. I only want it to show association name of the current admins-association.

Is there something i'm missing?

Still a newbie so appreciate all your help, folks!

---

models.py

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
        ...
        association = models.ForeignKey(Association)


class Event(models.Model):
        ...
        association = models.ForeignKey(Association)


class Association(models.Model):
        asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

---

views.py

```
def event_add_edit(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = CalForm(request.user, request.POST)
       res = {'success': False}

       if paramMissing(request.POST, 'name', res) \
             or paramMissing(request.POST, 'location', res) \
             or paramMissing(request.POST, 'start', res) \
             or paramMissing(request.POST, 'end', res) \
             or paramMissing(request.POST, 'allday', res) \
             or paramMissing(request.POST, 'description', res) \
             or paramMissing(request.POST, 'action', res) \
             or paramMissing(request.POST, 'association', res) \
             or paramMissing(request.POST, 'synced', res):
          return JsonResponse(res)

       action = request.POST['action']
       name = request.POST['name']
       location = request.POST['location']
       start = request.POST['start']
       end = request.POST['end']
       allday = request.POST['allday'] == 'true'
       description = request.POST['description']
       synced = request.POST['synced'] == 'true'
       asoc_id = form.request.POST['association']
       association = Association.objects.get(pk=asoc_id.pk)

       if action == 'add':
           Event.objects.create(
              name=name,
              location=location,
              start=start,
              end=end,
              allday=allday,
              description=description,
              synced=synced,
              association=asoc
           )

           res['success'] = True
           res['message'] = 'added'
           eid = Event.objects.latest('id').id
           res['eid'] = eid
           res['data'] = Event.objects.values().get(id=eid)
       elif action == 'edit':

           if paramMissing(request.POST, 'eid', res):
              return JsonResponse(res)

           eid = request.POST['eid']
           event = Event.objects.get(id=eid)
           event.name = name
           event.location = location
           event.start = start
           event.end = end
           event.allday = allday
           event.description = description
           event.synced = synced
           event.save()

           res['success'] = True
           res['message'] = 'edited'
           res['eid'] = eid
           res['data'] = Event.objects.values().get(id=eid)

       return JsonResponse(res)
   else:
       raise Http404
```

---

calendar.js

```
    $formwrappers: $(".form-wrapper"),
    $formclose: $(".form-close"),

   $addEventForm: $("#add-event-form"),
   $addEventAction: $("#add-event-action"),
   $addEventEid: $("#add-event-eid"),
   $addEventSynced: $("#add-event-synced"),
   $addEventTop: $("#add-event-top"),
   $addEventName: $("#add-event-name"),
   $addEventLocation: $("#add-event-location"),
   $addEventSdate: $("#add-event-sdate"),
   $addEventStime: $("#add-event-stime"),
   $addEventEdate: $("#add-event-edate"),
   $addEventEtime: $("#add-event-etime"),
   $addEventAllday: $("#add-event-allday"),
   $addEventDesc: $("#add-event-desc"),
   $addEventAsoc: $("#add-event-asoc"),

    showAddForm: function () {
       cal.$addEventAction.val("add");
       cal.$addEventSynced.val("false");
       cal.$addEventName.val("");
       cal.$addEventLocation.val("");
       cal.$addEventAllday[0].checked = false;
       cal.$addEventDesc.val("");

       var association = $(this).val("association");


       alert (association);

       $.ajax ({
          type: "GET",
          url: '/calendar/',
          data: association,
          success: function(data) {
              cal.$addEventAsoc.val(data);
          },
          error: function (error_data) {
              console.log("error");
              console.log(error_data)
          }
      });

      var date = new Date($(this).data("date"));
      cal.$addEventTop.text(date.toDateString());

      date.setHours(cal.currDate.getHours());
      date.setMinutes(cal.currDate.getMinutes());

      cal.$addEventSdate.val(date.toDateInput());
      cal.$addEventStime.val(date.toTimeInput());
      date.shiftHour(1);
      cal.$addEventEdate.val(date.toDateInput());
      cal.$addEventEtime.val(date.toTimeInput());

      cal.$addEventForm.addClass("visible");
  }
```

---

calendar.html

```
 <div class="form-wrapper" id="add-event-form">
    <form action="" method="POST" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" id="add-event-action" value="add">
        <input type="hidden" name="eid" id="add-event-eid" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="synced" id="add-event-synced" value="false">
        <ul>
            <li class="form-li">
                <span class="form-top" id="add-event-top"></span>
                <span class="btn-fa btn-close form-close">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="form-li">
                <span class="input-field">
                    <input id="add-event-name" maxlength="50" name="name" placeholder="Event Name" type="text" required>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="form-li">
                <span class="input-field">
                    <input id="add-event-location" maxlength="100" name="location" placeholder="Location" required>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="form-li">
                <span class="input-name">Starts</span>
                <span class="input-field datetime-field">
                    <input id="add-event-sdate" name="start_date" type="date" ><input id="add-event-stime" name="start_time" type="time" required>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="form-li">
                <span class="input-name">Ends</span>
                <span class="input-field datetime-field">
                    <input id="add-event-edate" name="end_date" type="date" ><input id="add-event-etime" name="end_time" type="time" required>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="form-li">
                <label for="add-event-asoc" class="input-name"> Association</label>
                <select id="add-event-asoc" name="association">
                    <option value="{{ association.id }}">{{ association.asoc_name }} </option> 
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="form-li">
                <input id="add-event-allday" type="checkbox" name="allday">
                <label for="add-event-allday" class="input-name"> All Day</label>
            </li>
            <li class="form-li">
                <textarea id="add-event-desc" name="description" placeholder="Description" maxlength="200"></textarea>
            </li>
            <li class="form-li">
                <input class="form-btn form-close" type="button" value="Cancel">
                <input class="form-btn btn-right" type="submit" value="Save">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

forms.py

```
class CalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    association = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Association.objects.none(),
                                     widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                     required=True)

    class Meta:
       model = Event
       exclude = ['last_login', 'date_joined']
       fields = ['association', ]

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
       super(CalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['association'].queryset = Association.objects.filter(asoc_name=user.association)
```

---

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^calendar/event/get/(?P<start>.+)/(?P<end>.+)/', views.event_get),
   url(r'^calendar/event/delete/', views.event_delete),
   url(r'^calendar/event/addedit/', views.event_add_edit),
   url(r'^calendar/', views.calendar.as_view(), name='calendar'),
]
```

Comment: Don't do all this `paramMissing` stuff. We have forms to do all of that; although if you're doing a lot of Ajax you might want to investigate django-rest-framework and its serializers.

Comment: Thank you, @DanielRoseman I will take a look and see what I can do=)